# Drag extra Id in joined Native query Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I've got some query:

```
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * From resource res " +
            "    join resource_group rg on res.resource_group_id = rg.id " +
            "    join user_resource_group_access urga on rg.id = urga.resource_group_id ", ResourceAccessEntity.class);
```

trying to map it to this:

```
public class ResourceAccessEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(columnDefinition = "UUID")
private UUID id;//user resource access Id here

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", columnDefinition = "UUID")
private ResourceEntity resource; //resource Id here

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "featureGroupAccessLevelsId")
private FeatureGroupAccessLevelsEntity featureGroupAccessLevels;
```

}

And I want to use as `id` of this mapping - urga.id and as res.id to put resource as a nested field. I will need to apply pagination, so i need everything done on db side. Appreciate any help.

PGresultSet conatins only following fields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple renaming of the field name solved problem:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(columnDefinition = "UUID")
private UUID superId;//user resource access Id here
```

This is the power of StackOverflow, struggled for 3 hours, and when asked a question in 5 minutes, a ready-made solution :)